# Can I dereference iterator in python like in C++?

Tags: python

I have a task: reverse bits from 8-bit string.

My implementation:

```
def inverse(s):
    for i in s:
        if(i == '1'):
            i = '0' 
        else:
            i = '1'
    return s
```

It doesn't work of course, but I don't understand how to make it work. So can I somehow change value from iterator `i`? Or at least how to solve my task simple and elegant?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You need to build another string to return. `i = ...` doesn't achieve anything since `i` gets overwritten in the next loop.

Comment: `i` is **not** an "iterator". On each iteration, the next element in the iterable `s` is assigned to the name `i`, to be used in the loop block, until the iterable is exhausted. Assigning something else to `i` does not change the element which was previously bound to `i`. And strings are *immutable* anyway, to "change" a string you have to construct a new one.

Comment: You can't "dereference" things in Python because Python *doesn't have pointers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in python are immutable, you can never change string after it is created. Well, you kinda can, but it will only create a new string. You need to create a new string to store result.

```
inverted = ''.join('0' if i == '1' else '1' for i in s)
```

`''.join()` creates string from iterable, `'0' if i == '1' else '1'` inverses bit and `(i for i in s)` is a generator, that applies inverter to each symbol in a string.

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't work of course, but I don't understand how to make it work. So can I somehow change value from iterator i?

You can't make it work. Python does not have pointers, and strings are immutable. So there's no way to modify a string at all, let alone through an iterator of its characters.

Here all you're doing is reassigning the local variable.

> Or at least how to solve my task simple and elegant?

Map over the old string, flip the characters, join to a new string.

Or use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), that's a fun if rarely used utility.

Answer (score 2):

*Or at least how to solve my task simple and elegant?*

You are replacing character-for-character, `.translate` method of `str` is useful for such task, consider following example:

```
bits = '01000100'
t = str.maketrans('01','10')
inverted = bits.translate(t)
print(inverted)
```

output

```
10111011
```

Explanation: I used `str.maketrans` to prepare translation table, when used in 2-argument form it requires two `str`s of equal length, character from first will be replaced with corresponding character from second, characters not present in first remain as is.

Comment: never knew about `str.maketrans`, it is mindblowing)

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
def inverse(s):
    return "".join("0" if i == "1" else "1" for i in s)

print(inverse("111000011"))
```

result:

```
000111100
```

Comment: FWIW the inner list is completely unnecessary. `str.join` works just fine with arbitrary iterables, such as a generator comprehension.